# How to correctly type-hint a function with `pyqtSlot()` decorator inside `QRunnable` class?

Tags: python, pyqt5, decorator, type-hinting

**Status**:

1. I'm learning how to use concurrency/threads within `PyQt` library from here [www.pythonguis.com](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/). Below is the simplified/part of code from this tutorial.
2. I want strict type hinting in my code. And I'm getting error messages on this code from `mypy`. (Shown on the 2-nd source-code block).

**Question**:

- How to correctly type-hint the function while using `pyqtSlot()` decorator?
- What is `Superclass` (that return `None`), and what is `Subclass` (that returns `str|None`) in this case?

**What I tried to solve:**

- My autistic ass doesn't sit well with error is showing on my text-editor. And I wasted too much time to solve single line. I couldn't find anything useful on the internet.
- The definition (or should I say `stub` file) says `pyqtSlot()` is:
  `def pyqtSlot(*types, name: typing.Optional[str] = ..., result: typing.Optional[str] = ...) -> typing.Callable[..., typing.Optional[str]]: ...`, I'm unable to interpret this due to no-experience on decorators.
- `stub` file: `QtCore.pyi` says that `Class QRunnable`'s `run` is: `def run(self) -> None: ...`.

```python
from typing import Callable
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

import traceback
import sys


class WorkerSignal(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn: Callable[[], str]) -> None:
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn:Callable[[], str] = fn
        self.signals: WorkerSignal = WorkerSignal()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self) -> None:   # <====================== this line
        try:
            result: str = self.fn()
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()
```

```sh
$ mypy /tmp/tmp.py
/tmp/tmp.py:22: error: Signature of "run" incompatible with supertype "QRunnable"  [override]
/tmp/tmp.py:22: note:      Superclass:
/tmp/tmp.py:22: note:          def run(self) -> None
/tmp/tmp.py:22: note:      Subclass:
/tmp/tmp.py:22: note:          str | None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

**EDIT**:

- Is the following guess correct?

  - `pyqtSlot()` takes function that returns `typing.Optional[str]` (i.e. `str | None`). Perhaps its the `subclass`?
  - `QRunnable`'s method `run()` only return `None`, Perhaps it's the `superclass`?
  - In this case, correct question would be: How to use decorator, if `decorator's return` and `function's return` are different? Would this be the correct question?

Comment: Well, this is a clear example that shows why it is *wrong* to focus too much on type hinting ahead of proper implementation and, above all, adequate knowledge about object behavior. Before worrying about the hinting of a pyqtSlot decorator, you should know that: 1. 99% of the times, that decorator is completely useless (as also explained by the PyQt developer), but, most importantly; 2. it can only work on classes that inherit from QObject, which is **not** the case of QRunnable.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with focusing wrong thing first. But on the other-hand, if there was no error in type-hinting, I wouldn't ever investigate `pyqtSlot()` at all. Saying that, I agree on having adequate knowledge (I'm still trying to improve)

Comment: It's just by "sheer luck" that it didn't crash at all: pyqt is "smart" enough to ignore its wrong usage. Then again, since by your own admission you've no experience in decorators, before fixating on type hinting (which, while extremely useful and important in development, is not essential in functionality of a Python program), take your time to actually study what decorators are, how they work, what they do and how the internal typing/representation works. You can pimp your car as much as you want, but that'll make you just dumb if you're not able to fix it because you forgot to fill the tank

Comment: I need to a lot of cold water. Because I need to apply cold water to the burned area.

Comment: I didn't mean to be harsh, I hope you didn't feel offended. But in the latest years I've seen sooo many people here posting code that has extremely detailed type hinting (even when completely unnecessary, or even inconsistent) while asking questions that most of the times could have been answered by simply studying the documentation or taking proper time (and focus) to understand the *real* problem. As said, hinting *can* be extremely useful and important, but shouldn't make us distract too much from the *main* priority of code: the functionality of the program and all its components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Other than the typehint you should not use pyqtSlot in a QRunnable method.**

The pyqtSlot decorator is only used in methods of classes that inherit from QObject and QRunnable is not. I have reviewed several tutorials that resort to this bad practice since it does not bring any benefit.

Comment: I see, What does `pyqtSlot` decorator do?  I have no idea why it's here, I don't understand explanation of it's usages.

Comment: @Garid    See the docs: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator You will see that in the official example it explicitly uses a QObject.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the type annotation for the `pyqtSlot` decorator in PyQt5 is wrong. The signature of your `run` function seems to be correct.

You can ignore the mypy warning with a `# type: ignore` comment. Alternatively, you can switch to PyQt6 where the type annotation for `pyqtSlot` is correct.

That said, whether you need the `pyqtSlot` decorator or not is an entirely different question (which I cannot answer).